# Mocking ActionBuilder's services when testing Play controllers

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework

I have recently created an ActionBuilder that inserts a user in the request based on the "Authorization" token sent in the request itself. I have been able to successfully unit test it by using the technique of splitting it into a trait (which is the element being tested) and a object that the only thing it does is extend that trait.

```
trait AuthenticatedTrait extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
  this: TokenServiceComponent =>
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
  [...]
}

object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedTrait with DefaultTokenServiceComponent with DefaultUserServiceComponent with TokenRepositorySlickComponent with UserRepositorySlickComponent
```

I also created a controller that uses this `Authenticated` action:

```
trait ProfileController extends Controller {
  def identity = Authenticated { implicit request =>
    Ok(request.user.email)
  }
}

object ProfileController extends ProfileController
```

Testing this controller manually it seems to work properly, but I would want to add some automated tests. This is the point where problems begin.

I would like to mock either the `ActionBuilder` or the service it uses, but as `Authenticated` is integrated as an object I can't see a way of doing it.

So, how do you test your `ActionBuilder`-using controllers?

Comment: I test my actions with controllers: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/test/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/core/SilhouetteSpec.scala#L354 You can also take a look at this test case: https://github.com/mohiva/play-html-compressor/blob/0.2/test/FilterSpec.scala

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing is creating a pair of traits that provide the action builder as an overridable method.

```
trait Authenticated {
  def authenticate: ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] = AuthenticatedAction
}

trait AuthenticatedMock extends Authenticated {
  def user: User

  object AuthenticatedActionMock extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
      block(new AuthenticatedRequest(user, request))
    }
  }

  override def authenticate = AuthenticatedActionMock
}
```

Then Controllers mix `Authenticated` and use `authenticate` on their actions. To test, `AuthenticatedActionMock` is mixed in and a user provided.